# What is the map unit specified by my CRS?

Tags: r, buffer, gis, raster, r-raster

I am rather new to spatial work with R and recently ran into the following issue:

I have gridded climate data (maximum temperature, monthly) and want to extract observations at some locations, using a circular buffer with a radius of 20KM. Let me first set it up and plot it...

```r
library(raster)

# load NetCDF file into SpatialRaster
ncin <- raster::brick(x='cru_ts4.05.1901.2020.tmx.dat.nc') 
#> Warning in .varName(nc, varname, warn = warn): varname used is: tmx
#> If that is not correct, you can set it to one of: tmx, stn

# get shape file
poly <- readRDS("C:/Users/m/shapes/gadm36_NGA_1_sf.rds") %>% 
  st_transform(proj4string(ncin))
ncin <- raster::crop(ncin, poly, snap = "out")
#clip raster outside the poly border
# result is a raster brick with dimensions (lat=20, lon=25, t=1440)

load ("C:/Users/m/NGA_panel.Rda") # load household data, with coordinates

# plot households as dots on the grid; see whether all parts display correctly!
plot(ncin$X2020.12.16, main="HH-locations")
# plot(poly$geometry, add = TRUE)
points(NGA_panel$LON_DD_MOD, NGA_panel$LAT_DD_MOD, pch=19, cex=0.5, col =1)
```

[Here](https://mathiasweidinger.com/TestKitchen/Rplot.png) is the resulting graph. The black dots represent households. For each of them, I want to extract a value from the grid, using a circular buffer with radius 20 KM. The value extracted is the mean of raster values within the buffer.

My CRS is `+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs`, which according to the [documentation of raster::buffer()](https://rdrr.io/cran/raster/man/buffer.html) does not necessarily have meters as its default map unit. `st_crs(ncin)` yields the following details:

```r
st_crs(ncin) # does the current crs take meters as length-unit?
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#>   wkt:
#> GEOGCRS["unknown",
#>     DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
#>         ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
#>         ID["EPSG",6326]],
#>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>         ID["EPSG",8901]],
#>     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#>         AXIS["longitude",east,
#>             ORDER[1],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
#>                 ID["EPSG",9122]]],
#>         AXIS["latitude",north,
#>             ORDER[2],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
#>                 ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

Does `LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]` above mean that a buffer radius will correctly be scaled in meters? Continuing with the extraction gives me...

```
NGA_spatial <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
  NGA_panel[108:107], proj4string=ncin@crs, NGA_panel) # spatialize dataset (i.e. make SPDF)
NGA_spatial <- NGA_spatial[sample(nrow(NGA_spatial), 100), ] #### LIMIT to 100 random rows FOR TESTING!

# extract values for households, using a circular buffer with radius 20KM:
data <- raster::extract(ncin,
                        NGA_spatial,     # SPDF with centroids for buffer
                        buffer = 20000,  # buffer size, units depend on CRS (meters or degrees?)
                        fun=mean,        # what value to extract
                        df=TRUE)         # create a data frame? 

summary(data[sample(ncol(data), 3)]) # summary statistics of 3 random columns
#>   X2005.09.16     X2000.02.15     X2001.02.15   
#>  Min.   :28.80   Min.   :29.20   Min.   :31.20  
#>  1st Qu.:29.77   1st Qu.:30.30   1st Qu.:32.17  
#>  Median :30.70   Median :33.30   Median :34.10  
#>  Mean   :31.21   Mean   :32.46   Mean   :33.63  
#>  3rd Qu.:32.25   3rd Qu.:33.80   3rd Qu.:34.55  
#>  Max.   :37.10   Max.   :35.00   Max.   :36.00
```

Clearly there is some variation in my extracted values, but I am uncertain whether this is extracted by a buffer of 20000 meters (as I want it to be) or a buffer of 20000 degrees (which would be absurd).

Can someone perhaps tell me whether this correctly extracts in meters and whether there is a way to control for that (e.g. by plotting the buffer somehow)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: units define the datum. a WGS84 with meters will interpret the angles (latitude, longitude) in meters, which make no sense. How do you define a 20km grid? (think about entire globe, it is not obvious, and you need a "center point". Just read as WGS84 and then transform in a metric coordinate, so you can use the grid

Comment: `crs(ncin) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"` does not change object's actual projection. It simply overwrites the crs attribute with incorrect information. `projectRaster()` changes the projection. `longlat` uses degrees as units and two degrees of longitude are differently far apart, depending on which latitude you are at. You need another projection, something like an azimuthal equidistant projection (`+proj=aeqd`), which uses meters as default and measures distances correctly under some conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo and @Chr for your comments. You are helping me to learn! I have slightly changed the post, because `st_crs(ncin)` (*before* dabbling with my crs) gave some output that includes `LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]`. Does this mean that it takes meters correctly after all?

Comment: No, that is the unit of the radius of the Earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `?raster::extract` for argument "buffer" states that

> If the data are not projected (latitude/longitude), the unit should be
> meters. Otherwise it should be in map-units (typically also meters).

`+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84` is clearly (?) latitude/longitude, so you should use meters.

This is illustrated in below, taken (with minor changes) from the examples in `?extract`:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18, vals=1:(18*36))
xy <- cbind(0, seq(20, 80, by=20))
xy
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0   20
#[2,]    0   40
#[3,]    0   60
#[4,]    0   80

extract(r, xy, buffer=1000000)
#[[1]]
#[1] 234 235 270 271
#[[2]]
#[1] 162 163 198 199
#[[3]]
#[1]  89  90  91  92 126 127
#[[4]]
# [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58
```

As you can see, you get increasingly more values (i.e., cells within the buffer) as you move pole-wards. This is as expected as the longitudinal distance decreases, roughly proportional to the `cos(latitude)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the grouping of the WKT:

```
#> Coordinate Reference System:
#>   User input: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#>   wkt:
#> GEOGCRS["unknown",
#>     DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
#>         ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
#>             LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
#>         ID["EPSG",6326]],
#>     PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
#>         ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
#>         ID["EPSG",8901]],
#>     CS[ellipsoidal,2],
#>         AXIS["longitude",east,
#>             ORDER[1],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
#>                 ID["EPSG",9122]]],
#>         AXIS["latitude",north,
#>             ORDER[2],
#>             ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
#>                 ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
```

There are 3 `*UNIT` blocks in there:

```
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
      ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
      LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]
```

and 2 Axis:

```
AXIS["longitude",east,
        ORDER[1],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
```

The first applies to the Ellipsoid (and is in metres) the other 2 are the ones you are interested in as they define how your data is stored (and presented) and are in degrees (as is expected with an unprojected WGS CRS). So your buffer will be in degrees and as you say will be absurd, provided nothing breaks it will return all of your data.

To work in metres you will need to reproject your data to a planar local CRS (preferably one that is EquiDistant for your dataset).

Comment: This may or may not be correct, depending on the software used. The OP is using raster (succeeded by terra), and as the other answer indicates, the buffer() function in either uses meters as the unit for lat/long projections.